# Prevent the line feed on the multiple-line minted code at the footnote

Tags: footnotes, line-breaking, minted

When I add a multiple-line minted code at the footnote, the minted code block is (automatically) line fed. See the image below.

I'd like to print the code at the same line as the footnote mark. How to do it?

I've tried the `\raisebox` method, no use. I've seen `\usepackage{bigfoot}`  being suggested, I've tried it, it gave an error on my code (It may not give an error on the MWE) I can't post my code as it's too long.

MWE:

```
% Prevent the line feed on the multiple-line minted code at the footnote
% lualatex --shell-escape main.tex 
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
% \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+0.6\baselineskip}{
% the code above gives error, no use.

In the \texttt{code}\cprotect\footnote{
\begin{minted}{python}
print("hello there")
\end{minted}
}
we note the use of the print function.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** Using `\mintinline` and removing the `\cprotect` achieves the desired output but it's limited to the one-liner code. I'd like to use multiple-line code there.

Comment: `minted` is a display construct, use `\mintinline`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the comment. I've tried with the `\mintinline` now. The situation's the same. Line feed is added to the footnote. Besides, I'd like to stick to the `\begin{minted}` structure because I plan to write multiple lines of program codes at the footnote.

Comment: minted is a display that explicitly adds vertical spacing before and after the code so it's not really expected to be on the same line as anything. mintinline is intented to work here (like `verbatim` compared to `\verb`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I appreciate the background info about  the `minted` adding vertical spacing on top of the minted code. I appreciate the quick solution of using `mintinline` too. It works fine (provided the `\cprotect` is removed) but it works solely for one-liner codes. I'd like to use multiple-line codes there. See the updated question. How to do it?